# Disable store load mask in Sencha 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

The Sencha store is automatically adding a ajax loader mask when populating the store, but I want to hide it since I have made a more generic mask which is shown every time the app does a ajax request.

How can I hide the store load mask? Tried to look in the documentation, but didnt find any appropriate field/method there:

See attachement:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The property exists: [loadingText](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-cfg-loadingText), which you have set to null.

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    store: 'Store',
    loadingText: null, // for ST 2.3.0 set it to false
    ....
}
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: doesn't work with ST 2.3.0. but setting it to false instead of null does work.

Answer (score 0):

> Olegtaranenko: Your solution does remove the loadmask, but setting the
>   loadingText to 'null' also seems to break the "PullToRefresh" plugin
>   functionality for a list.
>
> By 'break', I mean that after pulling the arrow down to refresh, the
>   ui remains in this state, and does not hide the PullToRefresh section
>   at the top.
>
> Is there a way to hide the additional loadmask, while retaining the
>   ability to pull to refresh?

For anyone that is reading this in future and is trying to achieve what I have described above, I worked around the issue with PullToRefresh by changing the original Sencha touch 1.1.1 code (line 45346 of sencha-touch-debug-with-comments.js).  This is not ideal, but provides a quick workaround.

**Original** (PullToRefresh breaks)

```
onBeforeLoad: function() {
        if (this.isLoading && this.list.store.getCount() > 0) {
            this.list.loadMask.disable();
            return false;
        }
    },
```

**Workaround**

```
onBeforeLoad: function() {
        if (this.isLoading && this.list.store.getCount() > 0) {
            try{ this.list.loadMask.disable(); }
            catch(err) {  }
            return false;
        }
    },
```

Comment: hmm... it does not break the PullRefresh plugin, at least in ST 2.0. I'm using this trick (with pull refresh) elsewhere and never noticed any problem. May be ST 1.1 has quirks, dunno

Answer (score 0):

Just add on your View

```
viewConfig: {
    loadMask: false
}
```