# Disable store extra loader

Tags: extjs, extjs6

So I have a grid panel that will show the data whenever I click the searched button and it will show the custom loader that I created. But it will also show the extra loader. How can I disable or hide the extra one? Btw I just upgraded from extjs 4 to extjs6 and during the extjs4 there's no extra loader. Just until the upgrade, it appeared.

I already tried this approach from here:
[Disable store load mask in Sencha 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421650/disable-store-load-mask-in-sencha-2)
but it will only remove the text and the extra loader is still there.

Here's a sample attachment:
[image]

Comment: What are you using to set loader?

Comment: just extended this class Ext.LoadMask, and created a custom one

Comment: @dummy can you create fiddle of this thing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting this on the view:

```
viewConfig: {
    loadMask: false,
}
```